# IE7 not respecting display: block on <ul> <li> <a>

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-7

I am attempting a simple vertical navigation using the following HTML markup:

```
<ul>
    <li><a></a></li>
    <li><a></a></li>
    <li><a></a></li>
</ul>
```

Despite having `display: block;` on both the `<li>` and `<a>` elements, IE7 does not appear to respect the full width of the containing div. Any ideas on this one?

http://jsfiddle.net/6eKGL/

[image: IE7 vs IE8+]

**UPDATE**

I now believe the issue is related to the `position` property of the container div and the fact that its width is to be determined by the content inside of the `<a>` elements.

Comment: block level elements are 100% the width of the parent element, even when padded and margined as long as their widths are not set explicitly. so it's better to set the width in the parent in this case, and block level children will conform.

Comment: @Derek Hunzinker Dear please have a look on my answer. Let me know if any issues. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the updated fiddle with IE-7 issue solved. http://jsfiddle.net/6eKGL/35/

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/6eKGL/35/embedded/result

CSS:

```
#ajax-search ul li a {
    display: block;
    /*min-width: 150px;*/ // Remove this rule and the IE-7 will start respecting the display block
    padding: 9px 18px;
}
```

**See below screenshot of IE-7**

[image]

Comment: Nice! Turns out this isn't related to my particular issue, but this answer does solve this thread.

Answer (score 1):

Setting `overflow: hidden` on the `<li>` element do the trick for me !

Answer (score 0):

try adding a doctype to your html, preferrably html5 or xhtml 1.0 strict. that way, IE7 renders in standards mode and not use it's own box model.

also, use a css reset. google for "eric meyer reset".

references:

http://www.quirksmode.org/css/quirksmode.html

http://meyerweb.com/eric/thoughts/2007/05/01/reset-reloaded/

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quirks_mode

**UPDATE:**

see this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6eKGL/23/

Comment: Thanks, I have XHTML 1.0 Strict set and I'm already using Eric Meyer's reset.

Comment: Why are you using XHTML 1.0 strict for HTML out of interest?

Comment: cleaner code and stricter semantics for an error free code. can be parsed as xml also

Answer (score 0):

Set `overflow:hidden` for **ul** and some wide width for **a**
http://jsfiddle.net/sergeir82/N2thx/

Comment: Thanks for your response. I like where you are going with this, however, if the content happens to be particularly long, it sneaks past the boundary of the container. See: http://jsfiddle.net/N2thx/1/

Answer (score 0):

Try after removing "min-width" from "#ajax-search ul li a {  display: block; padding: 9px 18px; min-width: 150px; }"